# Show and hide content by JavaScript from PHP script in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML table and want to show and hide class for multiple div separate only with javascript. This table will be generated from PHP script there will like 1000 tag.

I hope a smart javascript function can do this job:

```js
function showiteam() {
  document.querySelector(".zoom").style.display = "block";
}

function hideiteam(x) {
  document.querySelector(".zoom").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.zoom {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="showiteam()" onmouseout="hideiteam()">
      Google
      <div class="zoom">This Testing text</div>
    </td>
    <td>Yahoo</td>
    <td>Facebook</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="showiteam()" onmouseout="hideiteam()">
      Google
      <div class="zoom">This Testing text</div>
    </td>
    <td>Yahoo</td>
    <td>Facebook</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking?  What isn't working as expected?

Comment: i need this <div class="zoom">  show and hide when mousover  td

Comment: and i need that  Separate for etch coulm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `querySelector` returns only the first matched element.  You can use `querySelectorAll` to match multiple elements.  **However**, you probably don't want to show/hide *all* of the `.zoom` elements when hovering over any one table cell.

Instead, pass a reference to the table cell that's invoking the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events in the HTML, and call `querySelector` on that element so you're only matching the `.zoom` element contained within that cell:

```js
function showiteam(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".zoom").style.display = "block";
}

function hideiteam(cell) {
  cell.querySelector(".zoom").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.zoom {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="showiteam(this)" onmouseout="hideiteam(this)">
      Google
      <div class="zoom">This Testing text</div>
    </td>
    <td>Yahoo</td>
    <td>Facebook</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="showiteam(this)" onmouseout="hideiteam(this)">
      Google
      <div class="zoom">This Testing text</div>
    </td>
    <td>Yahoo</td>
    <td>Facebook</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent, excellent. Thank you for understanding what I mean. Thank you David

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correct what you 're asking, but this is what I would do

```
// in html
<td  onmouseover="showiteam()" onmouseout="hideiteam()"> 
     Google
     <div class="zoom is-hidden">This Testing text</div>
</td>

// in css (just replace .zoom with .is-hidden)
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}

// in js
function showiteam(){
   document.querySelector(".zoom").classList.remove("is-hidden");
}

function hideiteam(x){
    document.querySelector(".zoom").classList.add("is-hidden");
}
```

Comment: this code only show and i hide  only one item in table td and want to be all and Separate

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll say that a CSS solution would be easier, so I'll include that below.

But, since you specified Javascript in your question, I'll answer your question directly. The problem is that your querySelector is on the whole document, not on the event.target. So pure javascript fix is:

`event.target.querySelector(".zoom").style.display = "block";`

However, I really think the better solution would be to remove your javascript altogether, put the zoom class on the td and add this CSS definition:

`.zoom:hover div {display:block}`

That's a lot tidier, if you can do it.